# Apple now requiring iOS SDK 16.1 or higher for app store submission. How to I update if using EAS-CLI?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I am trying to do an EAS build using EAS-CLI and today I’m getting this error message:

```
Asset validation failed (90725)
SDK version issue. This app was built with the iOS 15.0 SDK. All iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 16.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 14.1 or later. (ID: a3310d95-f289-4afb-b067-2541ab2da007)
```

How do I get the build to utilize the most recent iOS SDK? I’ve tried adding a property with the 16.1 version number to my app.config.ts file but it results in errors. The project is using Expo version 44. Is that the issue or can I get around that somehow? Thanks in advance-

Answer (score 4):

Your Expo SDK version is too low.
Upgrade Expo SDK version to 48, EAS build will build app with Xcode 14.2 (iOS SDK 16.2)

Comment: thanks for the reply! got it sorted out after upgrading. :)

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve this by upgrading Expo SDK. Version 44 was deprecated so I needed to bring Expo more up to date. This article helped explain:

[Using outdated SDK versions](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/outdated-sdk-versions.md)